# Alignat with last line only aligning at one point

Tags: spacing, equations, formatting, alignat

I'm currently having this bit of code

```
\begin{alignat}{4}
\hat{\Theta}^2 |+\rangle &= \hat{\Theta}(i|-\rangle) &&= -i \hat{\Theta}|-\rangle &&&= - |+\rangle \\
\hat{\Theta}^2 |-\rangle &= \hat{\Theta}(-i|+\rangle) &&= i \hat{\Theta}|+\rangle &&&= - |-\rangle \\
& \Rightarrow\hat{\Theta}^2 &&= -1 &&&
\end{alignat}
```

yielding this:

[image]

I want the last line to only align the equal sign with the middle equal sign of the upper two lines but get this weird space in the last line because it also aligns the arrow. How can I fix this?

Comment: Unrelated but please always provide full minimal examples that others can just copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to help. You can do this using `\mathllap` from `mathtools`

Comment: There's a slight error -- noticeable in the form of uneven spacing around some of the `=` symbols -- in your code: The final `&&&` group in each line should be `&&`. Fixing this will also allow you to go from `{alignat}{4}` to `{alignat}{3}`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using `\mathllap{...}` on the left hand side of that particular alignment

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % autoloads amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4}
\hat{\Theta}^2 |+\rangle & = \hat{\Theta}(i|-\rangle)  &                                      & = -i \hat{\Theta}|-\rangle &  &  & = - |+\rangle \\
\hat{\Theta}^2 |-\rangle & = \hat{\Theta}(-i|+\rangle) &                                      & = i \hat{\Theta}|+\rangle  &  &  & = - |-\rangle \\
                         &                             & \mathllap{\Rightarrow\hat{\Theta}^2} & = -1                       &  &  & 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd have a couple of additional suggestions to [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675538/31283)'s answer (+1).

First, you may want to change the rightmost `=` to `{}=`. The equal sign will gain a proper spacing consistent to other two `=`s.

Second, it's more like a cosmetic suggestion. You could "improve" alignment of the terms after the middle `=` by adding an invisible `-`. This is done by `\phantom{}`. I quote "improve" because this might be more like a personal preference here.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4}
    \hat{\Theta}^2 |+\rangle &= \hat{\Theta}(i|-\rangle)   & &= -i \hat{\Theta}|-\rangle           & & &{}= -|+\rangle \\
    \hat{\Theta}^2 |-\rangle &= \hat{\Theta}(-i|+\rangle)  & &= \phantom{-}i \hat{\Theta}|+\rangle & & &{}= -|-\rangle \\
                    & & \mathllap{\Rightarrow\hat{\Theta}^2} &= -1 & & &
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT (thanks for the comment)
Below is one more example where the rightmost `=` is correctly formatted without any additional empty terms `{}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4}
    \hat{\Theta}^2 |+\rangle &= \hat{\Theta}(i|-\rangle)     & &= -i \hat{\Theta}|-\rangle          & &= -|+\rangle \\
    \hat{\Theta}^2 |-\rangle &= \hat{\Theta}(-i|+\rangle)    & &= \phantom{i} \hat{\Theta}|+\rangle & &= -|-\rangle \\
    & &                   \mathllap{\Rightarrow\hat{\Theta}^2} &= -1 & &
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be even better to change the instances of `&&&` toward the end of each line to just `&&`(and to change `{alignat}{4}` to `{alignat}{3}`).

Comment: @Mico Thanks. That's the detail I didn't know about. I was wondering why it would work and came to following conclusion: in your recommendation the last `&` forms a complete group of 2 columns in which `=` gains a proper type of relation, even though the left cells are empty.

Answer (score 2):

For complex alignments, `IEEEtrantools` comes in handy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\myket}[1]{\mathinner{\mathopen|{#1}\rangle}}
\newcommand{\hTheta}{\hat{\Theta}}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rClCrCl}
\hTheta^2 \myket{+} &=& \hTheta(i\myket{-})  &=& -i \hTheta\myket{-} &=& - \myket{+} \\
\hTheta^2 \myket{-} &=& \hTheta(-i\myket{+}) &=&  i \hTheta\myket{+} &=& - \myket{-} \\
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{r}{\Rightarrow\hTheta^2} &=& \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{-1}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

I defined `\hTheta` so to avoid repeating `\hat{\Theta}` too many times hindering readability of code. More important is `\myket`, that helps in getting better spacing.

The column types `r` and `l` are almost self-explanatory; `C` means “centered with spacing for relations”.

[image]

A possible improvement is to add `\!` in the `\IEEEeqnarraymulticol` (I noticed that it has a habit of adding thin spaces here and there).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\myket}[1]{\mathinner{\mathopen|{#1}\rangle}}
\newcommand{\hTheta}{\hat{\Theta}}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rClCrCl}
\hTheta^2 \myket{+} &=& \hTheta(i\myket{-})  &=& -i \hTheta\myket{-} &=& - \myket{+} \\
\hTheta^2 \myket{-} &=& \hTheta(-i\myket{+}) &=&  i \hTheta\myket{+} &=& - \myket{-} \\
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{r}{\Rightarrow\hTheta^2\!} &=& \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{-1} 
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]